# How can the image be any size orher than the object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

Am image is just the set of images of all the points on the thing. The complete image has to be the same size as the object if there is exactly one image for each point on the object forming it. So an image can't be smaller unless some of the points on the object haven't got an image in the complete one. It can't be even larger unless there are more than one point image for each point.

Comment: This may be a related analogy. Consider a map, $x\to 2x$, that takes the interval $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$. Would you agree that this map is bijective, but the domain and range have different sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You are never seeing "every point on an object", your eyes (as well as camera sensor arrays) have a finite number of light-sensitive receptors (or detectors, in case of cameras). You can roughly think of these as of pixels. They collect light from a small surface patch on an object (or from a large surface patch on an object, if it's far away), and what you see as that "pixel" is some sort of an averaged intensity of all those light rays.

Just like, in video games, a polygon on a character that's far away renders to only a few pixels, and a polygon on the same character that's near renders to a lot more pixels. The internal representation of the character is the same in both cases, and contains the same amount of data, it's just that the image of it is projected differently.

Now, real objects aren't made up of an infinite continuum of points, but the individual atoms are so tiny and the individual light rays are so numerous that we usually don't have to worry about any of that discreetness. So we can mathematically treat a surface of an object as a continuum (like a mathematical plane), and the thing about those is that you can stretch and squish them without ever loosing or adding any points at all, they always have infinitely many points. You can take two such planes and map a "larger" one to a "smaller" one, or vice versa, without introducing or loosing any information. (As DanDan0101 explained in a comment, in a map $x\to 2x$, every point is accounted for, as is in $x\to 0.5x$.)